# very strange error of image-webjpack-loader file-loader url-loader

Tags: webpack

I ran into a very strange error when I am using image-webpack-loader. I've commit a issue and it seems that the author is too busy to answer me. Does any body could solve my problem? I search for a long time but could not find an answer.
Here's my problem:

Recently, I ran into a very strange error with image-webpack-loader
My project were all right util I add some new vendor recently. I have 6 pages in my project and each page has it's style file. If 6 file has this code @import "../../cssBase/index.scss";, image-webpack-loader will have some errors. But if I delete this code in one of my pages, all errors have gone. I wonder why this would happen. Is it because I have too many images?

Here's my code:

```js
//my pages
const PAGES = ['home', 'profile', 'match', 'mall', 'goodsInfo', 'cartList']
//my webpack entries
let entry = {}
PAGES.forEach((page) => {
    entry[`js/${page}`] = ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', path.join(PATH.src, `view/pages/${page}/index.js`)]
    entry[`css/${page}`] = path.join(PATH.src, `view/pages/${page}/index.scss`)
    if(DEV) {
        entry[`js/${page}`].push('webpack-hot-middleware/client')
    }
})
//my image-webpack-loader configuration
let cfg = { 
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, include: paths,
    loaders: [
        'url?limit=2000&name=./img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?{progressive:true, bypassOnDebug:true, optimizationLevel: 3, interlaced: false, pngquant:{quality: "65-90", speed: 4}}'
    ]
}
```

```css
//my pages' style file contain this file, this file defines lots of variables and include some import file
@import "../../cssBase/index.scss";
```

Comment: Here's my errors:
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: spawn /Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant EAGAIN
at exports._errnoException (util.js:949:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuildFailed (/Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:315:19)
at nextLoader (/Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:270:31)

Comment: at /Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:292:15
at context.callback (/Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:148:14)
at imagemin.buffer.then.catch.err (/Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js:42:9)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: ERROR in ./feSRC/img/flags/GR_18X12@2x.png
Module build failed: Error: spawn /Users/Zero/projects/livebet-client-code/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant EAGAIN
at exports._errnoException (util.js:949:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&localIdentName=[path][name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]!./~/postcss-loader!./feSRC/view/pages/profile/index.scss 6:13630-13675